# Best practice to use multiple XML processors?

Tags: java

My project is using  multiple implementations of XML processors (Java default, saxon 9, xerces 2). So, for xml processing I have to tell which class to load for DocumentBuilderFactory and XPathFactory etc.
We can do it in several ways as defined in [Java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#DocumentBuilderFactory%28%29). What is good practice for this:

1. Use Constructor as introduced in Java 6 (Project already has dependency on Java 6)?
2. Use the javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory/XPathFactory system properties?
3. Use the properties file "lib/jaxp.properties" in the JRE directory?
4. Use the Services API?

Comment: Do you have a reason to use different processors?

Comment: Yes @Anon: saxon is being used for xslt 2.0 transformation and xerces2 java for schema 1.1 support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with option 1 as it's the least "magic". As an aside, last I checked the "Java default" XML parser was just a broken version of xerces.